# images.google appearing as referral traffic

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I see a decent amount of traffic, around 100 visits a day, that comes from an images.google domain but shows as referral traffic rather than organic in Google Analytics. I have some custom code to pull keywords out and set an organic source for a few variations of what Google Image Search referrers look like, and it works for every referrer I can run it against from the server log.

```
var ref = document.referrer;

if (ref.search(/www.google/) != -1 && ref.search(/imgres/) != -1) {
    var regex = new RegExp("www.google.([^\/]+).*");
    var match = regex.exec(ref);
    ref = 'http://images.google.' + match[1] + '?' + ref.split('?')[1];
    _gaq.push(['_setReferrerOverride', ref]);
} else if (ref.search(/maps.google/) != -1 && ref.search(/q=/) == -1) {
    var regex = new RegExp("maps.google.([^\/]+).*");
    var match = regex.exec(ref);
    ref = 'http://maps.google.' + match[1] + '?q=' + encodeURIComponent('(not provided)');
    _gaq.push(['_setReferrerOverride', ref]);
}

function splitUrl(url) {
    var vals = {};
    var split = url.split('?');
    vals.base = split[0];
    if(split.length > 1) {
        var vars = split[1].split('&');
        vals.params = {};
        for(var i = 0, len = vars.length; i < len; i++) {
            var valSplit = vars[i].split('=', 2);
            vals.params[valSplit[0]] = valSplit[1];
        }
    }
    return vals;
}

function joinUrl(urlObj) {
    var vars = [];
    for(key in urlObj.params)
        if(urlObj.params.hasOwnProperty(key))
            vars.push(key + '=' + urlObj.params[key]);
    return urlObj.base + '?' + vars.join('&');
}

//fix keyword for old google image search
if(ref.match(/^http:\/\/images\.google\./) || ref.match(/^http:\/\/images\.google$/)) {
    var refUrl = splitUrl(ref);
    if(refUrl.params.prev && !refUrl.params.q) {
        var prev = decodeURIComponent(refUrl.params.prev);
        if(prev.indexOf('?q=') !== -1 || prev.indexOf('&q=') !== -1) {
            var prevUrl = splitUrl(prev);
            refUrl.params.q = prevUrl.params.q;
            if(!refUrl.params.q)
                refUrl.params.q = encodeURIComponent('(not provided)');
            delete prevUrl.params.q;
            refUrl.params.prev = encodeURIComponent(joinUrl(prevUrl));
        }
        _gaq.push(['_setReferrerOverride', joinUrl(refUrl)]);
    } else if(!refUrl.params.q) {
        refUrl.params.q = encodeURIComponent('(not provided)');
        _gaq.push(['_setReferrerOverride', joinUrl(refUrl)]);
    }
}
_gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'images.google', 'q']);
_gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'maps.google', 'q', true]);
```

This handles all of the referres that look like:
http://images.google.com/?q=
and
http://www.google.com/?imgres=

I don't know where the referral traffic is coming from. Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: What do you see as the referralPath of the referral traffic from images.google.com?

Answer (score 0):

Well it is natural for Google to recognize this domain as a referral as GA only includes by default a certain number of domains as Search Engines.

To solve this problem you can include such domain as a Search Engine using the "addOrganic()" Method.

To use this method, you must specify not only the domain of the search engine, but also the query string parameter used for searches. In the case of images.google.com it's "q".

On your GA tracking code, add the line:
_gaq.push(['_addOrganic', 'images.google.com', 'q', true]);

You can get more info on the [Ga Help Site](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiSearchEngines.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._addOrganic).

Hope this info helps,

Augusto Roselli
Web Analytics - digitalcube
@_digitalcube
www.dp6.com.br

Comment: Sorry, I am actually already using _addOrganic, otherwise none of the Images traffic would show as organic. I've edited my original question to show that.

Answer (score 0):

If someone clicks on an image that shows up on standard google search, not images.google, the url might be different. You should try some urls from there. But besides that, the google images links that popup on normal Google will not include the query string if the user is logged in into a Google Account. It happened on Oct 2011 here are a couple of links on the subject:

- [Official Google Statement](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/10/making-search-more-secure.html)
- [Avinash's, always worth reading, opinion.](http://www.kaushik.net/avinash/google-secure-search-keyword-data-analysis/)

On normal organic google links Google Analytics shows these visits as coming from a `(not provided)` keyword from an organic medium. But if you click on an image on the SERP it won't be identified as an organic medium. It will be identified as a Referral, and that's probably the ones you are seeing.

**So what you need to do is to verify if the google images link has the `q` parameter or not. If it doesn't have than it's coming from a logged user and should be reported as `(not provided)` to be consistent with google organic keywords. Just append `&q=(not provided)` to the `_setReferrerOverride` url you got. Remember to url encode that before appending to the url.**

I'm also posting here the code I use. It's from [Google Forums](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/msg/analytics/5EWfEexJyUY/HSlOi6_GCSAJ). But it's very similar to yours and doesn't handle the `(not provided)` keywords issue yet.

Note that it's very similar to yours with a few notable differences.

- You strip the whole path from the images url, while mine keeps the
  path.
- You don't use the "true" keyword on "_addOrganic", that
  may cause Google Images to be reported as google instead of
  images.google source on your reports.

Here's the code I currently use:

```
//handle google images referrer
var ref = document.referrer; 
if ((ref.search(/google.*imgres/) != -1)) { 
  var regex = new RegExp("\.google\.([^\/]+)(.*)"); 
  var match = regex.exec(ref); 
  _gaq.push( 
    ['_setReferrerOverride', 'http://images.google.' + match[1] + 
unescape(match[2])], 
    ['_addOrganic', 'images.google', 'q', true] 
  ); 
}
```

I'll be updating my code to handle `(not provided)` google images links and will post here as soon as I have it.

Comment: Sorry but this is not very helpful. You mention checking the "q" parameter and setting it as "(not provided)" when appropriate, which I am already doing. The other issues you mentioned: stripping the path from the image url - this would not affect organic/referral, and setting "true" on addOrganic - this might result in it getting reported as the wrong organic source, but not a referral, which is the issue at hand.

Comment: You're right. I don't know how I missed that. Sorry for it. Where do you run this code? It must be ran after _setAccount but before _trackPageview, _trackEvent or _initData. That's what you do right? Other than that I don't know what could be causing you issue

Comment: No worries. Yes it is run after _setAccount and before _trackPageview